# IBM MQ Listener and Message adapter

Tags: listener, adapter, message

Is there a defined listener interface for IBM MQ or I should implement that using a running thread that pulls every some frequency and pass the message to a handler?
Also, is there a defined adapter between IBM MQ messages and standard JMS messages, or should I implement my own adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Look here, it has what you need.

[IBM MQ Spring Examples](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring)

You are looking for something like this...

```
public class Test {

@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
  DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
  factory.setConcurrency("5");
  configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
  return factory;
}

@JmsListener(destination = "DEV.QUEUE.1", containerFactory = "myFactory")
public void receiveMessage(String transaction) {
  System.out.println("Received <" + transaction + ">"+ "start time"+System.currentTimeMillis());
  
}
}
```